# Unobserved task exception under stress during WebSocket SendAsync

Tags: c#, exception, websocket, task, cancellation

I'm stressing a service I'm writing that uses a `WebSocket` taken from `AcceptWebSocketAsync`. The code I'm using to send messages through the WebSocket is this:

```
    static bool
    SendMessage(WebSocket webSocket, WebSocketMessage message, byte[] buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try {
            var endOfMessage = false;
            do {
                using(var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(webSocketsTimeout))
                using(var lcts    = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, timeout.Token)) {
                    var count    = message.Content.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    endOfMessage = count < buffer.Length;
                    // ReSharper disable once MethodSupportsCancellation
                    webSocket
                        .SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, count), message.Type, endOfMessage, lcts.Token)
                        .Wait() // SendAsync should be canceled using the Token.
                    ;
                }
            } while(endOfMessage == false);

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            TraceConnectionError(e);
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            message.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that under "stress" (I'm opening and closing 6 connections every 30 seconds until the system fails), I'm getting:

```
  Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection
     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.WriteAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<MultipleWriteAsyncCore>d__38.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendAsyncCore>d__47.MoveNext()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```

Shouldn't the `Wait()` I'm using be enough to "observe" the Task exception?

Comment: No. The "using" statement has its own exception handler.  Remove the using statement.

Comment: I don’t get what you mean. The using is not handling anything, the exception is thrown on the SendAsync(), and should be “observed” on the Wait()...if I remove the using I’ll just get a leak (at least on the LinkedTokenSource)...what I’m missing?

Comment: Internal to the using statement is a built in exception handler.

Comment: I understand what the using translates into (basically a try..finally with a dispose on the finally). How does that translation explain the behavior I’m seeing?

Comment: The exception says : An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection.  Probably the previous "using" timeout and you did not test that the connection was closed or null.

Comment: That exception is catch and reported by the `TraceConnectionError` the problem is that when the system reaches some level of connections it fails with an Unobserved Exception, which by my understanding should not happen, as I'm waiting for the `SendAsync` task to complete (the `Wait()` there). The fact that is that this exception is reported by a handler I have on `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`, and I have the system configured to stop on UnobservedTaskExceptions. I want to know why this exception is marked as unobserved!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155914/discussion-between-pablo-montilla-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a race condition in .NET framework code.

I've reported the bug [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129478/race-condition-on-websockethttplistenerduplexstrea.html).

As a workaround, I keep a list of used WebSockets which I regularly check for `State != Open` and then call this code:

```
public static class WebSocketXs
{
    readonly static Assembly  assembly                    = typeof(WebSocket).Assembly;
    readonly static FieldInfo m_InnerStream               = assembly.GetType("System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase").GetField(nameof(m_InnerStream), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    readonly static FieldInfo m_ReadTaskCompletionSource  = assembly.GetType("System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream").GetField(nameof(m_ReadTaskCompletionSource),  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    readonly static FieldInfo m_WriteTaskCompletionSource = assembly.GetType("System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream").GetField(nameof(m_WriteTaskCompletionSource), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    readonly static FieldInfo[] completionSourceFields    = {m_ReadTaskCompletionSource, m_WriteTaskCompletionSource };

    /// <summary>
    /// This fixes a race that happens when a <see cref="WebSocket"/> fails and aborts after failure.
    /// The <see cref="completionSourceFields"/> have an Exception that is not observed as the <see cref="WebSocket.Abort()"/>
    /// done to WebSocketBase <see cref="m_InnerStream"/> is just <see cref="TaskCompletionSource{TResult}.TrySetCanceled()"/> which
    /// does nothing with the completion source <see cref="Task.Exception"/>.
    /// That in turn raises a <see cref="TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static void
    CleanUpAndDispose(this WebSocket ws)
    {
        foreach(var completionSourceField in completionSourceFields) {
            m_InnerStream
                .GetValue(ws)
                .Maybe(completionSourceField.GetValue)
                .Maybe(s => s as TaskCompletionSource<object>)?
                .Task
                .Exception
                .Maybe(_ => {}) // We just need to observe any exception.
            ;
        }
        ws.Dispose();
    }
}
```